# Programming Puzzle - N Teams K Wins each

Tags: php, algorithm, programming-challenge

I found a problem [here](http://codeforces.com/contest/418/problem/A). I am sharing the problem and my attempt at solution. I would like to find out if this is the best approach possible.

> One day, at the "Russian Code Cup" event it was decided to play
>   football as an out of competition event. All participants was divided
>   into n teams and played several matches, two teams could not play
>   against each other more than once.
>
> The appointed Judge was the most experienced member - Pavel. But since
>   he was the wisest of all, he soon got bored of the game and fell
>   asleep. Waking up, he discovered that the tournament is over and the
>   teams want to know the results of all the matches.
>
> Pavel didn't want anyone to discover about him sleeping and not
>   keeping an eye on the results, so he decided to recover the results of
>   all games. To do this, he asked all the teams and learned that the
>   real winner was friendship, that is, each team beat the other teams
>   exactly k times. Help Pavel come up with chronology of the tournir
>   that meets all the conditions, or otherwise report that there is no
>   such table.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line contains two integers:  \$n\$ and \$k\$ (\$1 ≤ n, k ≤ 1000\$).
>
> **Output**
>
> In the first line print an integer \$m\$ - number of the played
>   games. The following \$m\$ lines should contain the information about all
>   the matches, one match per line. The \$i\$-th line should contain two
>   integers \$ai\$ and \$bi\$ (\$1 ≤ ai\$, \$bi ≤ n\$; \$ai ≠ bi\$). The numbers \$ai\$ and \$bi\$
>   mean, that in the \$i\$-th match the team with number \$ai\$ won against the
>   team with number \$bi\$. You can assume, that the teams are numbered from
>   1 to \$n\$.
>
> If a tournir that meets the conditions of the problem does not exist, then print -1.

My solution:

```
<?php
//$n = $argv[1];
//$k = $argv[2];
$s = fopen("php://stdin", 'r');
$n = stream_get_contents($s);
$dum= explode(" ",trim($n));
$n=$dum[0];
$k=$dum[1];
if ($n * $k > ($n * ($n - 1)) / 2) {
    echo "-1\n";exit;
}
$output = $n*$k."\n";
$winMap = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
    $winMap[$i] = 0;
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= $n; $j++) {
        if ($winMap[$i] < $k) {
            $output .= "$i $j\n";
            $winMap[$i] += 1;
        } else if ($winMap[$j] < $k) {
            $winMap[$j] += 1;
            $output .=  "$j $i\n";
        }
    }
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: This looks to me like a nice [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) question.

Answer (score 2):

**Style**

You are lacking consistency in the spacing in assignments.

**Organisation**

It might be worth extracting the algorithm in a function. It makes code easier to read and to test.

```
<?php
function guessChronology($n, $k)
{
    if ($n * $k > ($n * ($n - 1)) / 2) {
        return "-1\n";
    }
    $output = $n*$k."\n";
    $winMap = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $winMap[$i] = 0;
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= $n; $j++) {
            if ($winMap[$i] < $k) {
                $output .= "$i $j\n";
                $winMap[$i] += 1;
            } else if ($winMap[$j] < $k) {
                $winMap[$j] += 1;
                $output .=  "$j $i\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$s = fopen("php://stdin", 'r');
$n = stream_get_contents($s);
$dum = explode(" ",trim($n));
$n = $dum[0];
$k = $dum[1];
echo guessChronology($n, $k);
?>
```

**Re-using functions**

You can use [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to write `$winMap = array_fill(1, $n, 0);`